# Flutter isolate "Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:ui' Class: EngineLayer)"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have this problem where I am running some heavy function which I'll call foo. Since I'm trying to run foo at the same time as loading a page, I decided that using Dart Isolate to run concurrently was the best solution. However, what ends up happening is the Isolate doesn't run and it returns this error
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:ui' Class: EngineLayer)". Aside from the (what I believe to be necessary) context I provided below, I'd like to add that the Isolate.run is happening within a StatefulWidget, which, after looking online, might have an impact on the running of isolates. However, the foo function is defined outside of the widget class.

```
onNotification: (notification) {

//Page navigation code here

Map<String,dynamic> arg1; //Defined already
bool arg2; //Defined already
String arg3; //Defined already


List args = [arg1,arg2,arg3]

Isolate.run(() async {
foo(args); //Some static function
});

}
```

I don't know too much about isolates in general but googling the error shows this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89892 which says the problem is due to this https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36983. I tried a whole thing with Isolate.spawn, receive ports, and send ports but it was a lot more complicated and it ended up with the same error. Then I tried something with RawReceivePort but that didn't really work either (this was probably because I didn't know what I was doing). I'd like to emphasic note that I've tried running this function as a static function.

Comment: Change this anonymous function `() async {foo(args);}` to be either a top level or static function.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `foo` is `static` in this example, because you are not passing it `foo`. You are passing it an anonymous function which happens to call `foo`. The anonymous function is causing the problem not `foo`. You can replace the anonymous function with a static function like `static Future<void> myFunction() async {foo(args);}`, and then pass that in `Isolate.run(myFunction)`.

Comment: You might also need to make it a higher order function so that you can accept the arguments and still pass it a function. `static Future<void> Function() myFunction(List<dynamic> args) {return () async {foo(args);};}`, and then do `Isolate.run(myFunction(args))`.